# Python Selenium Webdriver Table Values to Excel

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, html-table

I am working on a project scraping a table off a web site. I will not be able to give full code as this is a company specific site with a login, hence my choice of Selenium. I have located the table in the HTML code:

```
class Table:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
    def get_row_info(self):
        table_id = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'dgTickets')
        rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
        col = []
        i = 0
        for i in rows[0]:
            i+=1
            name = i.text()
            col.append((name, []))
        for j in range(1,len(rows)):
            T = rows[j]
            i = 0
            for t in T.iterchildren():
                data = t.text_content()
                if i>0:
                    try:
                        data = int(data)
                    except:
                        pass
                col[i][1].append(data)
                i+=1
        Dict = {title:column for (title, column) in col}
```

This returns me an error that it is not an iterable value.

I think what I am trying to do here is relatively self explanatory. Primarily, I am trying to return the web table  and eventually get it into a pandas dataframe for parsing. Using various methods, I can get the columns to print out their texts, but there seems to be a problem with passing that to a specified column in a table. Here is one way that I have found to return the column:

```
        for row in rows:
            col0 = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[0]
```

I'm honestly a little lost at this point. Any suggestions for me?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: first suggestion: always show full error message - it shows in which line is error. We can't run it so we can't see errors.

Comment: second suggestion: use `print()` and `print(type(...))` to see what you have in variables. OR learn how to use debugger.

Comment: some code makes no sense - ie. `for i in rows[0]: i+=1` - `rows` is a list but you get first element from list `rows[0]` and you try to use it as list `for i in rows[0]` and when you even get it as `i` then you treats it as number `i += 1` - but later you treats it as object `i.text()`. If using `i += 1` you try to get next element then it is wrong. OR maybe you have to use the same variable for two differene elemen - `i = 0` and `for i in rows[0]` - but Python can't keep keep two different values in the same variable.

Comment: BTW: if page uses standard tags to create table then you can use [pandas.read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) to get all tables on page as list of `DataFrames`  -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pandas.read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) to get all tables on page as list of `DataFrames`. It works very fast.

```
import selenium.webdriver
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

# --- get table ---

all_tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source, attrs={'id': 'constituents'})
df = all_tables[0]

# --- show it ---

print(df)
```

---

If you want to do it manually - but for this example it takes much longer.

```
import selenium.webdriver
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

# --- get table ---

headers = []
columns = dict()

table_id = driver.find_element_by_id('constituents')
all_rows = table_id.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")

# --- headers ---

row = all_rows[0]
all_items = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("th")
for item in all_items:
    name = item.text
    columns[name] = []
    headers.append(name)

print(headers)

# --- data ---

for row in all_rows[1:]:
    all_items = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
    for name, item in zip(headers, all_items):
        value = item.text
        columns[name].append(value)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns)

# --- show it ---

print(df)
```